# Seleccionar un rango variable en VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Tengo una tabla en una hoja Excel.

Necesito seleccionar y asignar a una matriz un rango variable que depende de dos variables: *DiaInicial* y *DiaFinal*.

La primera columna de la tabla es un campo fecha con este formato:

```
dd/mm/aaaa;
```

Ésta tabla dispone de 4 columnas adicionales, siendo un total de 5 las columnas a seleccionar entre ambas fechas.

De esta manera el rango de filas y columnas comprendido entre *DiaInicial* y *DiaFinal*, será el objeto a seleccionar.

Para tener una idea más clara, tenemos el siguiente ejemplo:

> [image: Ejemplo]

En la tabla anterior, necesito seleccionar y asignar a una matriz el rango comprendido entre `DiaInicial = 23/09/2010` y `DiaFinal = 29/09/2010`.

Es decir, la macro debe leer el rango delimitado entre ambas fechas y asignar el rango a un matriz.

¿Cómo se puede realizar esta selección?

Comment: Cómo quieres darle los valores de DiaInicial y DiaFinal?

Comment: Hola Lamak: No se si te he entendido bien, ambas variables deberían ser de tipo Date....

Comment: me refiero a que quieres que se asigne un rango que depende de dos variables. Tú quieres crear una macro que haga eso?, si es así, cómo quieres pasarle las variables DiaInicial y DiaFinal?

Comment: Ok, entendido, si una macro. Es decir, hay dos variables de tipo Date que toman valor al principio, La macro debe buscar en el rango de la tabla y almacenar los datos en un Array

Comment: ¿En qué aplicación se encuentra almacenada la tabla? ¿[tag:excel],[tag:ms-access-2007], [tag:mes-access-2010], otra?